# Elasticsearch Connector for Presto does not support username and password

Tags: presto, trino

We have hosted an elastic search V7.11.2 on our non-cloud ecosystem. We are using presto V0.248 to connect to it.
Our Elastic Search is secured with a basic authentication system (currently is NON-SSL) we are able to connect but due to authentication enabled we are getting 401 HTTP status. As per the documentation we currently don't see any header adding or option to add username or password to presto connector.

Any help or pointer on how to enable the same.

Answer (score 0):

Prestodb doesn't support user/password authentication for Elasticsearch. You may want to look at Trino (a fork of prestodb by its creators and major contributors, [formerly known as PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)), which has had this feature since [version 337](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-337.html#elasticsearch-connector) (latest version is 354): https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/elasticsearch.html#elasticsearch-auth-user